# how reverse proxy load balancer is different from non reverse proxy load balancer(TCP proxy/SSL proxy)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Sorry for the basic question, but I was not able to find the difference between `proxy` and `non proxy load balancer(TCP/ssl)` in `Google Cloud`. I have gone through below link but I am not able to understand the difference between them and when to use what:

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/tcp

Request you to help me understand what is the difference between two and where we will use `proxy` and `non proxy load Balancer`.

Thanks.

Comment: Do not use the term "non proxy". The two primary types are `proxy` and `pass-through`. Knowing those details will not help you much. You need to understand the differences between Layer 3/4 and Layer 7 load balancers. The differences between UDP and TCP.. How to configure SSL/TLS and where. Pass-through load balancers are rarely used except in specialized configurations. Layer 7 (HTTP/HTTPS) is the most complex and common load balancers now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference is that TCP load balancer (non proxy) just forwards the request to your backends (pass-through) without doing anything more than giving you a public or private IP, and the ability to distribute the load between the instances in your backend. While TCP proxy/SSL LB end the connection at load balancer layer and then forwards the request to your backend. So you can add, for example, a certificate in this kind of LBs.

Link for layer4 proxy LBs:

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/tcp

Link for layer 4 non proxy LB:

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network

Comment: Thanks for spending your valuable time on my query.

1) Your answer make sense. 
2) Whether proxy is enable or not, you can add certificate in SSL load balancer. Do you mean to say that ssl offloading takes place at VM Level when we select SSL LB without proxy enabled and if proxy is enabled on ssl the ssl offloading will take place at load balancer level?

Comment: SSL load balancer have a proxy (SSL Proxy Load Balancing), that's the reason why you can add a certificate there, and it will take place at load balancer level.
I think you might be confusing LB types, for proxy you have both, TCP proxy LB and SSL proxy LB. The only LB without proxy is TCP/UDP LB which are pass-through and you can't configure certificates there.